# how to takeout and check the value of a number in a mixed(text+number) txt file using python

Tags: python-2.7

How can I use Python to take and check the value of a special number in a mixed txt file.
for example the txt file is like this:

```
#header 
897843
 #comment
21   12321  3213  0983
21   1231  323  09323 
21   121  3213  09003
#text
 8932 234 5464
```

Then I only need to check second number in the first line after the #comment (i.e. 12321) whether it is greater than a value(like 13255) or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tag = False
f = open("mix.txt")
for line in f:
    if tag:
        nums = line.split()
        if int(nums[1]) > 13255:
            print("greater")
        else:
            print("lesser")
        break
    if '#comment' in line:
        tag = True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChenZhongPu. I am trying to make the comparison by taking the so called 13255 number from another textfile with same structure. I tried to store the comparing value(as you mentioned in your code with "nums[1]") into a string and put it in the next steps as below. But seems it is far away wrong than what it should be. I will appreciate it if you help with that:

Comment: @AramA. your code here is out of format. I cannot see what it is.

Comment: @ ChenZhongPu: Yeah, Sorry,I am not very familiar with text editing here. trying to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

```
tag = False
g = open("mix0.txt") 
    for line in g:
        if tag: 
            nums = line.split()
            x = float(nums[1])
            tag = True 
        if '#comment' in line: 
               tag = True 
f = open("mix1.txt") 
    for line in f: 
         if tag:
             nums = line.split() 
             if float(nums[1]) > x : 
                  print("greater") 
             else: 
                  print("lesser") 
             break 
          if '#comment' in line: 
             tag = True
```

Comment: @ChenZhongPu: I had to write it here to make it clear. hope it does not make mistake for other users.